# Assigning values to time dependent variables in Train/Test sets

Tags: cross-validation, partitioning

In a dataset with history of customer visits, I have a variable denoting 'Days since last visit'. I have done a stratified train/test split of the data.

How should I assign values to this variable? Should I use only the visits from the training set to assign values (This will assign incorrect value to the 3rd visit if the 2nd on is in test set)? Or should I assign values to the whole set together irrespective of the split?

How far should we take the 'training data should never see the test data' thing?

Or is it a better option to split the data by time? First 9 months in training, next 3 in testing?

Comment: taking this tip.. _if any other feature whose value would not actually be available in practice at the time you’d want to use the model to make a prediction, is a feature that can introduce leakage to your model_ from [here](http://machinelearningmastery.com/data-leakage-machine-learning/), I assigned the value to the whole set.